# debsign fails due to GPG error

Tags: linux, gnupg

Am Trying to build a debian package from source, it signs the package once the source builds. 
Am able to build package on my desktop but same package build is failing on my VNC session which is the same desktop.

```
success on desktop:
----------
Now signing changes and any dsc files...
signfile <file1>.changes info@abc.com
gpg: key 9F54A1B3: secret key without public key - skipped

Successfully signed changes file

---------------------------

Error on VNC: 
----------
Now signing changes and any dsc files...
signfile <file1>.changes info@abc.com
gpg: key 9F54A1B3: secret key without public key - skipped
gpg: problem with the agent - disabling agent use
debsign: gpg --no-tty --passphrase tigris error occurred! Aborting....
debuild: fatal error at line 1283:
running debsign failed
```

Do I need to add anything to the keyring may be.  Here is the gpg key list

```
root@vdeore:/home/vdeore/ws/VCA# gpg --list-keys
/root/.gnupg/pubring.gpg
------------------------
pub   1024R/A3888BE1 2015-01-15
uid                  vdeore <info@abc.com>
sub   1024R/9965A356 2015-01-15

pub   1024R/EAE69D3A 2015-01-15
uid                  abc <info@abc.com>
sub   1024R/79C683AB 2015-01-15
```

Tried generating key on VNC, but it did not make any difference. 
Any suggestions ? Appreciate the help, thanks in advance.